# Sculpted Object Doesnt Show in Edit Mode?

Tags: modifiers, sculpting

I sculpted a shark in sculpt mode, I then click preview on the Multi-res modifier and it just appears as a sausage shape thing with no fins or mouth etc that i added. How do i solve this?

Screen-shot from sculpt-mode:
[image]

Screen-shot from edit-mode:
[image]

Multires settings:

[image]

Thanks for any help you can give, Rob

Comment: ignore the right hand screen, here are some photos; http://imgur.com/sU0aaHi

Comment: and here is when i go to edit mode; http://imgur.com/JSqWpyM

Comment: and here is my settings on the right; http://imgur.com/8dJ98gF

Comment: In your multires modifier , you set the Preview to 1 and Sculpt and Render to 10 , increase the Preview level to 10

Comment: please crop your images to include only relevant information. To make a screen capture within blender press Ctrl F3

Comment: I apologize for the wrong answer (deleted), as @MrZak pointed out, you cannot see multiresolution effect in Edit Mode, since there's no option to view it in Edit Mode to activate, unlike Subdivision modifier.

Comment: okay thanks, so is my object stuck like that? because i was following a tutorial for a school project and i need to make the shark move. when i render it will the sculpt appear?

Comment: The basic mesh is too low poly, I'm not sure it'll animate right anyways, so you can try copying the object, decrease the levels to a reasonable value to get more details for animation, try level 2 or 3, see if that works and apply the multires modifier, then you can bake the normal map from the high res object to the low res poly, this is the right way to get high details on an object that can be used for animation or a game. Please consider editing your question, remove the unnecessary parts of the images.